# Azure API Management logs request and response bodies

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, ibm-api-management

I would like to log the request and response bodies of my API calls in Azure API Management for debugging purpose.

To do that I have created a Log Analytics workspace and configured the diagnostic settings to store the logs in it. But when I check the logs in Log Analytics tool (*Logs of the last 100 calls*), I see my API calls with status code, subscription key, etc but **the body columns are always empty**.

I tried to enable the body request logging in the API Azure Monitor advanced settings but it doesn't change a thing, still empty bodies and headers.

Do I have forgotten something or is there a notion of Azure Monitor that I do not understand?

Comment: Microsoft deployed this feature 2 weeks ago, so now I have the request and response bodies in my logs when I activate body logging in the Azure Monitor tab of the API setting 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there isn't anything you forgot to configure the monitor for APIM, I also test it in my side and also can't see the `requestbody` and `responsebody` column in logs.

Here find an [answer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/73055) from MSFT about this problem for your reference, I think that's the official answer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @hury-shen, I have searched on github but not the right repo apparently. I hope Microsoft will implement this feature soon.